# Need advice on Ajax fileupload

Tags: php, html, jquery, file-upload

I am trying get use of Ajax file uploader
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

The doc says:

```
var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
    // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
    element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
    // path to server-side upload script
    action: '/server/upload'
    // WHAT IS action:?
});
```

The **element** property means what element ID is used as Upload button. 
What is **action**? It must be some sort of handler for uploaded files?

How I can handle uploaded files and where are located?

The doc says

```
// events         
// you can return false to abort submit
onSubmit: function(id, fileName){},
onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total){},
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){},
onCancel: function(id, fileName){},
```

I want when upload complete display a list of files somewhere, say in div with ID=list

The short snippet will be highly appreciated and awarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used File Uploader quite a lot and I think it is the best file uploader out there.

The action is the method (URL) which receives the call from your Ajax client script.
You have to define a DIV in your HTML:

```
<div id="uploaderFile"></div>
```

I've used a javascript function to build my uploader around the DIV:

```
function CreateImageUploader() {
    var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
        element: $('#uploaderFile')[0],
        template: '<div class="qq-uploader">' +
                              '<div class="qq-upload-drop-area"><span>Drop files here to upload</span></div>' +
                              '<div class="qq-upload-button ui-button ui-widget ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-state-default">Seleziona il Listino Excel</div>' +
                              '<ul class="qq-upload-list"></ul>' +
                              '</div>',
        hoverClass: 'ui-state-hover',
        focusClass: 'ui-state-focus',
        action: 'Home/UploadImage',
        allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'gif'],
        params: { },
        onSubmit: function(file, ext) {

            },
        onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
            $("#PopupImageUploader").dialog('close');
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What happens here is you're creating an uploader around this element element: `$('#uploaderFile')[0]`. I've used the standard template but you can change the appearance.
When you've done that everything is pretty much setup on the client-side.
On the server side (it depends what you're using) you have to intercept and read the file and persist it.
I use ASP.NET MVC. You can find my action [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5272619/how-do-i-perform-a-ajax-jquery-upload-of-an-image-in-asp-net-mvc/5273352#5273352) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789993/what-is-the-best-way-to-upload-files-with-asp-net-mvc-2/4792528#4792528)
Your server-side code will manage to persist the file where you want and will return infos to the client script.
Personally I return json data which I manage with the event `onComplete` to: close a dialog  (like in the example); show a message etc etc etc.

If you want to pass parameters back to the client on the server side you can return a JSON object. I would do something like this:

```
return ("{success:true, newfilename: '" + newFileName + "'}");
```

I reckon that in PHP could be something like this:

```
echo {success:true, newfilename: '" + newFileName + "'}";
```

Forgive me if there are mistakes in that but I've never written a single PHP line in my whole life ;-)

the client side now can check the JSON object  like this:

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
   alert(responseJSON.newfilename);
}
```

As you can see I pass back the result of the action: `success:true` or `success:false` so I can show a warning to the user:

```
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON) {
if (responseJSON.success)
{
    alert(responseJSON.newfilename);
}
else {
    alert("something wrong happened");
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my serverside is PHP.

Comment: I think my problem is that I simly have a few knowledge on how AJAX works. I still cant figure out how it works - so the URL handler is not loaded in the browser but is just called?

Comment: if you're using PHP you can use their example here: https://github.com/valums/ajax-upload/blob/master/server-side/upload-handler.php Yes, the URL is the server side code you use to persist the file you've chosen from your disk.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias! One more question please - how can I pass back parameters from PHP to client? Say I am saving files in PHP under different names and I want to pass back names

Comment: I return a JSON string. I'll update my answer with some more infos.

Comment: OMG I was too lazy to look what is the package - they have sample

Comment: action is path relative to what?

Answer (score 1):

> How I can handle uploaded files and where are located?

This depends on your webserver and backend language. In PHP have a look at the `$_FILES` array.

> What is action? It must be some sort of handler for uploaded files?

The URL the form used to upload the file is submitted to.

Comment: Let me put it other way how can I set php handler page. When I upload using <form> it is "action=" and here?

Answer (score 1):

> What is action? It must be some sort of handler for uploaded files?

Yes, same as for the HTML `<form>` element's [attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#adef-action).

> How I can handle uploaded files

With a server side script written in your server side language of preference.

> and where are located?

Probably as a stream to STDIN. The forms library you use with the aforementioned server side language have methods to extract it automatically.

Comment: Thank you David. But I dont get the following. Uploading using old school <form> will make my browser simply load other (or the same) php page that is specified as handler. How it works for ajax uploader? Sorry lame question, I keep learning.

Comment: I haven't, and don't intend, to go through the third party code you are using. It probably posts a form to a hidden iframe.