# ASP.NET MVC 3 - File Upload

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I need to implement a file uploader action within it. For some reason, when I post my form, the Request.Files collection is empty. I have been able to confirm this by setting a breakpoint. So I know that I'm reaching the action. However, I can't figure out why the Request.Files collection is empty. Here are my relevant HTML, AreaRegistration, and Controller snippets.

**index.html**

```
<form action="/files/upload/uniqueID" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div>Please choose a file to upload.</div>
    <div><input id="fileUpload" type="file" /></div>

    <div><input type="submit" value="upload" /></div>
</form>
```

**MyAreaRegistration.cs**

```
context.MapRoute(
  "FileUpload",
  "files/upload",
  new { action = "UploadFile", controller = "Uploader" }
);
```

**UploaderController.cs**

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult UploadFile(int uniqueID)
{
  foreach (string file in Request.Files)
  {
    // I never get here :(
  }

  return View();
}
```

I have not made any changes to the default web.config file. Is there some setting I need to add? I can't figure out why the Request.Files collection would be empty. Can someone please help me?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Have you tried using the `Html.Form()` helper?

Comment: possible duplicate of [File upload MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/765211/file-upload-mvc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use HttpPostedFileBase for you controller and do something like that

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file) 
{

    if (file.ContentLength > 0) 
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/"), fileName);
        file.SaveAs(path);
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

And for the view

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <label for="file">Filename:</label>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />

    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Check Phil Haack blog here for this problem: [Uploading a File (Or Files) With ASP.NET MVC](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/07/16/uploading-files-with-aspnetmvc.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with your `action` attribute in your `<form />` tag:

```
action="/files/upload/uniqueID"
```

I think upon post it is trying to pass the string `"uniqueID"` to your Action method.  When you hit your breakpoint, what is the value of your `uniqueID` parameter set to when you reach the action method `UploadFile()`?

Use the [`HtmlHelper.BeginForm()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492692.aspx) method to use Razor to construct the form.

Comment: I need to POST a value for UniqueID though. In other words, I need to POST an ID value and a collection of Files to upload. How do I do that?